# wordpress select multiple options and illegal string offset 'timeslot'

Tags: plugins, php, plugin-development

```
<form method="POST">
<select name="timeslot[]" multiple="multiple" size = 4 required>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" name="submit"/>
</form>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    global $wpdb;
    $booking_timeslots = $wpdb->prefix . 'booking_timeslots';   
    $timeslots = $_POST['timeslot'];
       foreach ($timeslots as $time) {
          echo $dd = $time['timeslot'];
       }
}
?>
```

This is my full code with query.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    global $wpdb;
    $booking_dates = $wpdb->prefix . 'booking_dates';   //'booking_dates' is a table name which is in the database
    $booking_timeslots = $wpdb->prefix . 'booking_timeslots';   //'booking_timeslots' is a table name which is in the database

    $year = $_POST['year'];
    $month = $_POST['month'];
    $days = $_POST['days'];
    $timeslots = $_POST['timeslot'];

        $data['year'] = $year;      // $data['year'] year is a name of column in database
        $data['month'] = $month;
    foreach ($days as $day) {           // $data['month'] month is a name of column in database
        $data['day'] = $day;            // $data['day'] day is a name of column in database

        $wpdb->insert($booking_dates,$data);
        $last_record_id = $wpdb->insert_id;

        foreach ($timeslots as $timeslot) {
            $data_timeslot['bid'] = $last_record_id;
            $data_timeslot['time'] = $timeslot;
            $wpdb->insert($booking_timeslots,$data_timeslot);
        }
    }
}
?>
```

While above code executes wordpress gives following error.

```
Illegal string offset 'timeslot'
```

Can someone help to resolve this.

Comment: please Elaborate your question.

Comment: Please change `name="timeslot[]"` to `name="timeslot"`.

Comment: Please check by change your select box options values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting `illegal string offset 'timeslot'` **because** `$time` **is not an array, it is an item in array** `$timeslots`. You have already retrieved the values submitted using `$timeslots = $_POST['timeslot'];`

Your code also contains other typing mistakes.
Here is corrected code:

```
<form method="POST">
   <select name="timeslot[]" multiple="multiple" size = 4 required>
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
   </select>
   <input type="submit" name="submit"/>
</form>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    global $wpdb;
    $booking_timeslots = $wpdb->prefix . 'booking_timeslots';   
    $timeslots = $_POST['timeslot'];
    // you can use print_r() here 
    print_r( $timeslots );  // to see what is submitted from form

    foreach ($timeslots as $time) {
          echo $time;
    }
}
?>
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: @AfzalKhan Stay blessed!

Comment: would you give me 1 more favour ?

Comment: yes, if possible for me.

Comment: i have a problem in query

Comment: What is the problem? Can you share the code?

Comment: '$wpdb->insert($booking_timeslots,$time);'  

i have this query but it is not working. don't know why.

Comment: @Afzal Khan, what is table name in database and what fields are there?

Comment: i'm gonna update my code 
you can chek the full code there .

Comment: Any db or PHP error?